# SESSION_start does not let me see a page

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

So I try to do a php logIN system, but I have problem with the $_SESSION, when i put the condition to open the account.php page with user and Password, i don t know why don t let me to login if the user and pass is in the database and is corect

login.php page

```
<?php   if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $PW = $_POST['password'];   

    $result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE Username='$user' AND Password='$PW'");
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

    session_start();    
    $_SESSION["userID"] = $row['userdID'];
    header('Location: account.php');
    }

?>
```

account.php page

```
<?php require 'conx.php'; ?>

<?php session_start(); 
if(isset($_SESSION["userID"])){
    } else{
        header('Location: login.php');
        }
?>

<p>MY ACCOUNT<?php echo $_SESSION["userID"]; ?> </p>
```

and the DB structure

```
`userID`, `Name`, `Email`, `Username`, `Password`, `Timestamp`, `Userlevel`, `ProfileImage`, `Bio`
```

Comment: What happens exactly when you enter the correct username and password?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL-Injections](http://bobby-tables.com/). Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) the values to the query. Take a look at [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: ok i understand i m vulnerable to sql injection, how i can fix that, the problem mention i fixed, but how i can fix the sql injection can you write me please a exemple??

Comment: @StefanJ. you said that you fixed your initial problem. if one of the answers helped you, please select it (and upvote if you wish). If you figured it out on your own that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you login.php you must change like this:

```
<?php  session_start();  
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
$user = $_POST['username'];
$PW = $_POST['password'];   

$result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE Username='$user' AND Password='$PW'");
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

  echo 'ROW =>'.$row['userdID'];
$_SESSION["userID"] = $row['userdID'];
//header('Location: account.php'); // for see if you have something in row
}
?>
```

And in your account.php page, you have a blank line between require.. and the other

you must put session session_start(); before any html objet ( echo or line, 
.. )

you account.php must be like this:

```
<?php session_start(); 
require 'conx.php';
if(isset($_SESSION["userID"])){
} else{
    header('Location: login.php');
    }
?>

<p>MY ACCOUNT<?php echo $_SESSION["userID"]; ?> </p>
```

Comment: still doesnt work, after logIN doesnt open the page account.php, it is still relog the login.php

Comment: i figured up... it was $row wrong the variable, thank you

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have a blank line before the session stuff. This forces an output to start, preventing any session related stuff to be properly handled. If you remove the first closing tag and second opening tag in the account.php file, you should be golden.

Comment: if he used ob_start() before session_start() that would solve his problem too right?

Comment: Possibly, don't know that off the top of my head. Even if it did, it's working around a problem that shouldn't really exist in the first place. Removing the problem is better than fighting the symptoms.

Comment: how i can do that can you give me a exemple?

Comment: Like so:

    `<?php require 'conx.php'; 
    session_start(); 
    if(isset($_SESSION["userID"])){
        } else{
            header('Location: login.php');
            }
    ?>

    <p>MY ACCOUNT<?php echo $_SESSION["userID"]; ?> </p>`

Comment: Syntax highlighting doesn't seem to work in comments

Answer (score 2):

Hi `session_start` should be at the top without any blank space and `echo` statement

```
 <?php 
session_start(); 
  if(isset($_POST['login'])){

        $user = $_POST['username'];
        $PW = $_POST['password'];   

        $result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE Username='$user' AND Password='$PW'");
        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);    
           if($row){
        $_SESSION["userID"] = $row['userdID'];
        header('Location: account.php');
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: i did this, but still doesnt work, when i logIN doesnt open the account.php is only relog the page login.php....

Comment: ok that means your $_SESSION["userID"] has no value have you tried to echo it in account.php. Try <?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION["userID"]; die; at top of account.php to see it has userId or not

Comment: ok then your session is not created in login page. is  $row['userdID']; has something or not??

Comment: what do you mean?  I don t understand you... if i echo $_SESSION["userID"] doesn t appear the number of the id of the database

Comment: that means when you set $_SESSION[userId] in login page it has no value means in login page your query not returing true.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of problems right away:

1. In **login.php** you never bother to check whether a record with the correct username and password was found. After the query, you just call `fetch_array` without checking whether a row was returned.
2. In **account.php**, you `session_start` *after* having sent output to the browser. Do not exit PHP mode after `require 'conx.php'`. Remove the closing and opening tags `?> <?php` otherwise, the space between the tags is sent to the browser and your sessions break.
3. You are completely exposed to sql injection attacks as you do not create prepared statements. You passwords are clearly not hashed. See [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Comment: ok so what i can fix that can you give me a exemple please...â